# How to Use Count(Distinct) for Oracle Analytic View Aggregations

Tags: oracle, analytics

I'm using Oracle Analytic Views (from 19c) as defined here: https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/dwhsg/overview-analytic-views.html

I can create measures with simple aggregations (eg: SUM, COUNT, MIN), but I can't create a measure that collates COUNT(DISTINCT). I've tried both calculated and basic measures, without success. So,

*How do I define a measure that is equivalent to COUNT(DISTINCT(x)) ?*

Some example SQL to show my issue is (which I can run in livesql.oracle.com):

```
create table sales_fact (
    CUSTOMER_ID VARCHAR2(50 CHAR),
    COUNTRY VARCHAR2(50 CHAR),
    PRODUCT_ID VARCHAR2(50 CHAR),
    ORDER_ID VARCHAR2(50 CHAR),
    MONTH_ID VARCHAR2(30 CHAR)
    );

insert into sales_fact(CUSTOMER_ID, COUNTRY, PRODUCT_ID, ORDER_ID, MONTH_ID) values ('A', 'France', '1', 'A1', 'Apr-11');
insert into sales_fact(CUSTOMER_ID, COUNTRY, PRODUCT_ID, ORDER_ID, MONTH_ID) values ('A', 'France', '2', 'A1', 'Apr-11');
insert into sales_fact(CUSTOMER_ID, COUNTRY, PRODUCT_ID, ORDER_ID, MONTH_ID) values ('A', 'France', '1', 'A2', 'Jun-11');
insert into sales_fact(CUSTOMER_ID, COUNTRY, PRODUCT_ID, ORDER_ID, MONTH_ID) values ('B', 'England', '2', 'B1', 'Jul-11');
insert into sales_fact(CUSTOMER_ID, COUNTRY, PRODUCT_ID, ORDER_ID, MONTH_ID) values ('C', 'Germany', '2', 'C1', 'Aug-11');
insert into sales_fact(CUSTOMER_ID, COUNTRY, PRODUCT_ID, ORDER_ID, MONTH_ID) values ('D', 'Germany', '3', 'D1', 'Apr-12');

create table time_dim (
    MONTH_ID VARCHAR2(30),
    MONTH_NAME VARCHAR2(40),
    YEAR_ID VARCHAR2(30),
    YEAR_NAME VARCHAR2(40)
);
insert into time_dim(MONTH_ID, MONTH_NAME, YEAR_ID, YEAR_NAME) values ('Apr-11', 'April', '11', 'CY2011');
insert into time_dim(MONTH_ID, MONTH_NAME, YEAR_ID, YEAR_NAME) values ('Jun-11', 'June', '11', 'CY2011');
insert into time_dim(MONTH_ID, MONTH_NAME, YEAR_ID, YEAR_NAME) values ('Jul-11', 'July', '11', 'CY2011');
insert into time_dim(MONTH_ID, MONTH_NAME, YEAR_ID, YEAR_NAME) values ('Aug-11', 'August', '11', 'CY2011');
insert into time_dim(MONTH_ID, MONTH_NAME, YEAR_ID, YEAR_NAME) values ('Apr-12', 'April', '12', 'CY2012');

CREATE OR REPLACE ATTRIBUTE DIMENSION time_attr_dim
USING time_dim
ATTRIBUTES
 (year_id,
  month_id)
LEVEL MONTH
  KEY month_id
  DETERMINES (year_id)
LEVEL YEAR
  KEY year_id;

CREATE OR REPLACE HIERARCHY time_hier
USING time_attr_dim
 (month  CHILD OF year);

CREATE OR REPLACE ANALYTIC VIEW sales_av
USING sales_fact
DIMENSION BY
  (time_attr_dim
    KEY month_id REFERENCES month_id
    HIERARCHIES (time_hier DEFAULT)
  )
MEASURES
 (salesCount FACT ORDER_ID AGGREGATE BY COUNT,
  orderCount FACT ORDER_ID AGGREGATE BY COUNT -- How to make this count(distinct)?
 )
;

-- 2011 should have a salesCount = 5 and orderCount = 4 (if it was distinct)
SELECT YEAR_ID, salesCount, orderCount
FROM sales_av HIERARCHIES(time_hier)
WHERE time_hier.level_name = 'YEAR'
ORDER BY time_hier.hier_order;
```

Answer (score 0):

One answer I have found is that "AGGREGATE BY COUNT DISTINCT" only works on numeric columns.
So, something like:

```
order_count FACT DBMS_UTILITY.GET_HASH_VALUE(ORDER_ID,0,65536) AGGREGATE BY COUNT DISTINCT,
```

can work, but the count is based on hashing, and will be inaccurate for large data sets.
If I replace the fact table column with an INTEGER column, then the values need to be less than 64991, otherwise the bitmap operator used by the analytic view produces an error during query (which seems quite a limitation to me).

A better answer though is to use "AGGREGATE BY APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT" which uses the HLL algorithm. That is only accurate to about 4%, but avoids the need to be a numeric column with values less than 65k.

Comment: If anyone has a suggestion about how to perform count distinct with higher cardinality (more than 65000 different values) I'd appreciate their ideas!